# PHP preg_split keep special characters inside double quotemarks

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm using regex in preg_split to split a string into separate parts.

```
$string = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name" column="1/2"';
$ps = preg_split("/\s(?![\w\s]+\")/u", $string);
echo '<pre>',print_r($ps,1),'</pre>';
```

The above code gives the following result and is working correctly:

```
Array
(
[0] => text
[1] => required
[2] => name="first_name"
[3] => label="First Name"
[4] => column="1/2"
)
```

But if I add any special characters inside the double quotemarks the string is broken down into separate array items:

```
$string = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name! $ , ." column="1/2"';
$ps = preg_split("/\s(?![\w\s]+\")/u", $string);
echo '<pre>',print_r($ps,1),'</pre>';
```

Resulting in:

```
Array
(
[0] => text
[1] => required
[2] => name="first_name"
[3] => label="First
[4] => Name!
[5] => $
[6] => ,
[7] => ."
[8] => column="1/2"
)
```

How can I keep "First Name! $ , ." in the same array item?

e.g. like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => text
[1] => required
[2] => name="first_name"
[3] => label="First Name! $ , ."
[4] => column="1/2"
)
```

Comment: Can you have escaped `"` characters inside the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for splitting:

```sh
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+
```

**Code:**

```sh
php > $string = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name! \"$ , ." column="1/2"';
php > $re = '/"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/';
php > print_r( preg_split($re, $string) );
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => required
    [2] => name="first_name"
    [3] => label="First Name! \"$ , ."
    [4] => column="1/2"
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lfQ2vR/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`: Match a quotes string that may include escaped characters
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: Skip and fail this match
- `|`: OR
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespace

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match_all` here with the following alternation:

```regex
\w+=\".*?\"|\b\w+(?!\S)
```

This pattern will attempt to match a `key="value"` entry.  That failing, it will try to match a standalone word which is followed either by whitespace or is the last word in the input.

PHP code:

```php
$input = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name! $ , ." column="1/2"';
preg_match_all("/\w+=\".*?\"|\b\w+(?!\S)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => required
    [2] => name="first_name"
    [3] => label="First Name! $ , ."
    [4] => column="1/2"
)
```